# "Вообще" as opposed to "совсем"

Tags: выбор-слова

Does the placement and choice of "вообще" as opposed to "совсем" make any difference and which "filler/parasite" words are the most fitting in colloquial speech? Thank you!

Я вообще не знаю.

Ну я не знаю, вообще.

Ну я просто не знаю  /  Ну вот я просто не знаю

Вот, я совсем не знаю.

Я так не знаю вообще.

Ну я какк-то вообще не знаю.

Ну я вообщем совсем не знаю вообще.

Ну я просто как-то совсем не знаю, как-то как.

Я совсем вообще не знаю.

Comment: Did I make a mistake with how I asked my question? I asked as best as I could and didn't capitalize the words in question. I assumed it was strictly pertaining to grammar, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some meanings of **вообще**.
 1В общем, в большей части случаев.In most cases, in general

> **Вообще**, это верно.

2. Adverb. Всегда, при всяких условиях . always

> Этот человек **вообще** необщителен.

3. Adverb. Взяв в целом, в общем, обобщая. On the whole.

> Я говорю о людях **вообще**, а не о тебе.

4. Introductory word Used when one thing is opposed to another.

   > Над ним всегда смеются, хотя **вообще** он прав. **Вообще** он чудак, но с ним интересно.

   И вообще(разг.) Conjunction connecting the idea more general than the previous one.

> Он гулял, купался **и вообще** отдыхал.

Совсем and вообще coincide only in the meaning "completely, absolutely" Вообще is colloquial. Used more often.But in written speech it's better to use совсем.

Now your examples, which words are fillers and which are meaningful ? **Я не знаю**.is a general idea.
Я вообще не знаю.Absolutely ( stressed )

Ну я не знаю, вообще.--Introductory word.,ну--filler.

Ну я просто не знаю / Ну вот я просто не знаю--Ну--filler, просто--emphatic filler,вот--filler.

Вот, я совсем не знаю.вот--filler,совсем--absolutely.

Я так не знаю вообще.так--emphatic filler вообще--absolutely.

Ну я как-то вообще не знаю.ну-filler, как‐то uncertainty filler, вообще--absolutely

Ну я в общем совсем не знаю вообще.--Ну--filler, в общем--in general, совсем--absolutely

Ну я просто как-то совсем не знаю, как-то как.--Ну--filler, просто--emphatic filler, как‐то uncertainty filler, совсем--absolutely, как‐то так--uncertainty filler 
Я совсем вообще не знаю.Sounds weird.

**Ну** and **вот** are  most frequently used fillers, youngsters use *блин*, there are other words used as fillers depending of habits and culture as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I cant find this type of info in books. An Ingush  man just told me some things today about how they speak in the Caucasus :
Что ста́ло?  - Что случилось? / Что произошло?
My questions are about specific things and I dont know why I have gotten thumbs down votes that theyre not well thought out. lol. Theyre things that arent common to ask about it and not found in books.

Comment: Don't get upset